# C# - Data from ___.aspx to ___.cshtml with a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, viewbag

I'm new to C# - ASP.NET and I'm trying to drop data ,from a filled form, from .aspx to .cshtml.

I made a form with three TextBoxes and a Button, a method for the "onClick". This method set the value of ViewData (name,date,user) with the values of the three TextBoxes. And I want to collect these value on the page targeted by the form.

I do not get any error but ViewData(name,date,user) seems to be empty.
Here's my code :

*CSHTML*

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Consulter";
}
@Html.Partial("MenuBar")
@Html.Partial("Connexion")
@ViewData["name"]
<style type="text/css">
    ...
</style>
...
<h2>...
```

*ASPX*

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<script language="C#" runat="server">

        public void Ajouter(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewData["name"] = dateForm.Text;
            ViewData["date"] = dateForm.Text;
            ViewData["user"] = userForm.Text;
        }

 </script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AjouterForm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ajouter un produit</h1>
    <div>
        <form id="form1" runat="server"  action="Consulter" defaultbutton="bouton1" method="get">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox placeholder="Name" runat="server" ID="nameForm"/></br>
    <asp:TextBox placeholder="Date" runat="server" ID="dateForm"/></br>
    <asp:TextBox placeholder="User" runat="server" ID="userForm"/></br>

    <asp:Button runat="server" text="Envoyer" ID="bouton1" onClick="Ajouter"/>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1" />

</div>
</form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you know how to solve it or if you have another way to do it, it would be amazing :)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this MVC? Or Web Pages?

Comment: This is MVC, the 2 files are some views

Comment: Did you know in MVC, you don't post data to a view? You post data to a controller, which will pass the data to a view. So ViewData is not appropriate here.

Comment: Hmmm... ok. So I've to target my controller with the __.aspx then using a method to drop it to the __.CSHTML ?

Comment: You should avoid ViewData/ViewBag as much as possible. Your controllers should communicate with your views by passing them a View Model.

Comment: Your Web Forms page should post the data to a URL that hits an action method on your controller. The specific URL used depends on your routing. Then your controller will return a view, passing the model as a parameter. These are all very basic MVC concepts. I think you need to work your way through [some tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc) or read some MVC books to get a solid grasp on this stuff.

Comment: Ok, I just began 5 days ago I don't really get the "MVC" logic. Thank you for your advices